# Using the difflib.HtmlDiff class - showing single chars

Tags: python, difflib

I am using the [`difflib.HtmlDiff`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.HtmlDiff) class, calling the function using two sets of text (HTML from websites), however when it makes the table

```
html_diff = difflib.HtmlDiff()
print html_diff.make_table(previous_contents, fetch_url.page_contents)
```

however that just seems to compare char by char (1 char per table row), and I end up with a 4.3MB txt file for two sets of html which are only 100k.

The doc file says,

```
Compares fromlines and tolines (lists of strings) and returns a string which is a 
complete HTML file containing a table showing line by line differences with 
inter-line and intra-line changes highlighted.
```

however that doesn't seem to be the case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're supplying strings, not lists of strings (lines).

Assuming UNIX or Windows line ends:

```
print html_diff.make_table(previous_contents.split('\n'),
                           fetch_url.page_contents.split('\n'))
```

Comment: Your answer was useful to me thank you. Do you know how we can reduce width of output diff (it shows a very wide width of both first and second file) ?

Comment: @msashish That sounds like an unrelated question. Go [ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)! If you want, you can [drop me an email or message](https://phihag.de/) with the URL.

Comment: I found the answer. Constructor difflib.HtmlDiff() can take wrapcolumn parameter..thanks anyways